# Example public live stream for IIS smooth streaming

Tags: iis, live, live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I'm interested in a publicly available live stream (with `IsLive=true` in the manifest file) in the IIS smooth streaming format. The content doesn't matter. I'd like to test some software if it supports live streams properly. Where can I get such a stream?

Installing and configuring my own webserver (IIS) instance is not an option, I need a publicy available live stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the two sources below:

- http://demo.anevia.com:3128/live/disk1/live1/ss-ss/manifest, or
- http://demo.anevia.com:3128/live/disk1/live2/ss-ss/manifest